# Replacement for underscore's toArray

Tags: javascript, meteor, underscore.js

I am working on a super simple meteor app and found some code that does almost exactly what I want, but has a dependency on underscorejs.   I have never used underscorejs and prefer not to have that dependency (I have certainly heard that underscore is great, but I just don't want to deal with any unnecessary packages at this time).   This is the only line that uses underscorejs:

```
this.channels[name].args = _.toArray(arguments);
```

Would rewriting the toArray function be trivial or is there some heavy lifting going on underneath the hood?

The code came from this blog entry: http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteorjs-package-only-app-structure-with-mediator-pattern and is located in the Mediator object example.

Thanks!

Comment: Underscore is an integral and currently inseparable part of meteor. Therefore it is going to be included in your project regardless of you declaring a dependency on your package. Also, there is an ongoing assessment to swap underscore for lodash in not so distant future. Also, these libraries are very efficient in what they do and are huge boost to developer productivity. Therefore, I sincerely suggest you to get to know them and you'll be very happy that you did.

Comment: The code I was using was old and had explicitly included underscore library.   When I got an undefined error I didn't pay proper attention and immediately thought it was due to not including underscore -- but that wasn't the issue.   The _.toArray is working without including that package, just as @SerkanDurusoy explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arguments` is an iterable object, although it's not explicity an `Array`. If you don't care about JS engine implications, you can simply convert it to a real array. This allows you to treat `arguments` like an array and perform array methods. You can just do:

`this.channels[name].args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);`

Another way is:

`this.channels[name].args = Array.apply(null, arguments);`

If you want to replace `_.toArray()` and not depend on the  underscore library, you can do something like:

`_.toArray = function () { return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)[0]; };`

**ES6 will have the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) which does what you want elegantly**:

```
function someFunction(...args) { 
    this.channels[name].args = args;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is the native [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object, you can iterate and create an array

```
var arr = [];

for (var i=0; i<arguments.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = arguments[i]
}
```

or you can use the native `Array.prototype.slice.call`, shortened with `[].slice.call`

```
var arr = [].slice.call(arguments);
```

Note that MDN specifically says

> You should not slice on arguments because it prevents optimizations in
>   JavaScript engines (V8 for example). Instead, try constructing a new
>   array by iterating through the arguments object.

Comment: if it's a one-time call to init a channel, surely the computing cost (optimized or not) is negligible, so readability/convenience are just as important factors. `[].slice.call(arguments)` has been plenty fast for me on stuff that doesn't happen all the time. for an init routine it's very unlikely to be a problem. good to mention though...

Comment: @dandavis - I use `[].slice.call` all the time on arguments, and never had any issues with it, I think we're talkning about milliseconds at worst, I've just noticed the MDN warning several times before, and thought it best to mention it.

Answer (score 0):

If you rate underscore and trust what's it's doing, you could just use its toArray method found here: http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-46

```
_.toArray = function(obj) {
  if (!obj) return [];
  if (_.isArray(obj)) return slice.call(obj);
  if (isArrayLike(obj)) return _.map(obj, _.identity);
  return _.values(obj);
};
```

Unfortunately, underscore uses underscore! So you'd have to implement `isArray`, and `isArrayLike` also :P

Maybe the source can give you some ideas for how you'd like your implementation to work?

Also, take a look at the lodash source. That too might provide some inspiration: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/lodash.js#L8983